# Successive Derivatives of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I've tried to find a general closed-form for the kth derivative of the function 
$$ f:x\mapsto (1+e^x)^n$$
where $n$ is a positive integer.

The first terms are :
$$ f':x\mapsto ne^x(1+e^x)^{n-1}$$
$$ f'':x\mapsto f' + n(n-1)e^{2x}(1+e^x)^{n-2}$$
$$ f''':x\mapsto f'' + 2(f''-f') + \frac{n!}{(n-3)!}e^{3x}(1+e^x)^{n-3}$$

So I guess there is a general patern, but I don't know what it is.
Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

We can expand with Binomial Theorem.
$$
f(x) = (1 + e^x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}e^{kx}
$$
To compute $f^{(m)}$, simply differentiate each term in the sum $m$ times::
$$
f^{(m)}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}(k^m)e^{kx}
$$

Comment: Actually I don't want to use the binomial theorem, because I want to find the closed form of $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k^p$ for all $p$.

Comment: The Wikipedia page on [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Sums_of_the_binomial_coefficients) may help.

Comment: @KeryannMassin: you are asking an XY question then.

Comment: What do you mean by XY question ?

Comment: "The XY problem is a communication problem encountered in help desk and similar situations in which the real issue, X, of the person asking for help is obscured, because instead of asking directly about issue X, they ask how to solve a secondary issue, Y, which they believe will allow them to resolve issue X."

Comment: Hmm well yes you're right xD